# Using Google Map or Mapquest to get a map on a client/server application

Tags: .net, google-maps, dictionary, bing-maps, mapquest

I know it's pretty easy to integrate a map from google map, mapquest or other on a Web application, but I was wondering if it's possible to integrate a map on a normal client/server application (WPF).

In fact, I do not even want to see it on my application,  but I would like to print an image version of a map in a report. this report would gives the user a perspective on where to go.

Is this possible, if yes which system is the best (google,mapquest,bing, any other?). It's obvious that the computer will need to be connected to the internet, but this will not be from a web app like mentionned before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to get a PNG image of a map.
- You can [embed an interactive flash map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html)
- You can use [this Bing Maps control](http://bingmapswpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Note that you're only allowed to embed Google maps in printed materials if they make use of a "distinctive aspect of [Google's] products" - http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Answer (score 2):

Pretty good MSDN article on using Bing Maps SOAP Services with WPF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx

Comment: Note that that cannot create an interactive map.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want a map image to embed in a static (printed?) report, then I'd use one of the Bing Maps services. You can create an image based on a variety of styles (road, aerial, hybrid etc.) either using a SOAP interface, or via REST.

Method reference for the SOAP Imagery service is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981090.aspx, and there's a worked example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx

Alternatively (and my preferred method), you can use the REST interface, described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx. Using this interface, you can make a simple URL request, and optionally display pushpins, routes, or other info on the map based on parameters passed in the URL.

Either way, you'll need to sign up for a Bing Maps key first from https://www.bingmapsportal.com.

Answer (score 0):

[MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com) offers a [Static Maps web service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/) as well and it might be worth a look. I believe it's possible to include the static maps in printed reports, but it may have a licensing cost involved. You'll want to check the licensing terms just to be sure.